# Entering Italy: I've been in Greece in the last 14 days but I'm travelling from Germany, do I need to do Quarantine?

Tags: italy, covid-19, quarantine

[This document](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/dettaglioContenutiNuovoCoronavirus.jsp?lingua=english&id=5412&area=nuovoCoronavirus&menu=vuoto) by Italy's Ministry of Health states that

> Movements to/from EU countries (except for Romania and Bulgaria) are
> allowed without the need of justification, therefore also for tourism,
> and without the obligation of isolation on return provided that you
> have not transited or stayed in the territories belonging  to lists C,
> D, E, or F in the 14 days prior to entering Italy. The requirement to
> fill in a self-declaration remain.(Except for the Republic of San
> Marino and the Vatican City State)
>
> Croatia, Greece, Malta, Spain: the Minister of Health, with an
> Ordinance of 12 August 2020, in addition to what is already provided
> for EU countries, has established that those who enter/return to Italy
> from these countries (after a stay or even only transit) from 13
> August and until further notice, must also:
>
> a) [...]
>
> b) undergo a molecular or antigenic test; to be swabbed upon arrival
> at the airport, port, or border location (where possible) or within 48
> hours of entering the national territory at the reference local health
> unit.

So my understanding is that I'll need to take a test in the airport, but I don't know if I have to wait for the test results in my hotel or I can move freely unless they call me telling me that I tested positive.

Comment: The way the rules are piled up on top of each other is somewhat confusing but your interpretation seems correct.

Comment: Self-isolation is mandatory

Answer (score 2):

[This webpage by the Italian Embassy in Athens](https://ambatene.esteri.it/ambasciata_atene/it/ambasciata/news/dall-ambasciata/2020/03/coronavirus-rientro-in-italia-dall.html) is available in Italian and Greek but not in English. It was published in March 2020 and updated on Dec. 8, 2020 (this question was asked in September 2020 and the answer to it may change again in the next months).

It states (by Google Translate):

> 2. Starting from 10 December 2020, the following preventive measures will also apply:
>
> ...
>
> b) Anyone who enters Italy and has stayed or transited in Greece between 21 December and 6 January must only observe the obligation of "quarantine" (health surveillance and fiduciary self-isolation of fourteen days), a negative swab is not requested. Only for those who have stayed or passed through Greece, in the same period, for reasons attributable to (a) work needs; b) absolute urgency; c) health needs; d) study needs; e) return to their home, home or residence, there is an obligation to submit the results of a negative swab carried out in the 48 hours prior to entry into the national territory (while there is no obligation to quarantine).